# Multiple monitors under X: eliminating gaps due to different monitor heights

Tags: linux, xorg, x-windows, nvidia-settings

I am using `nvidia-settings` to configure multiple monitors . The monitors' native resolutions are different, so this generates 'gaps' where the items are drawn on the virtual screen but not on any of the physical ones.

[image: Multiple screens with gap at the bottom]

How can I configure the display settings to not have any content drawn on the regions which are not directly mapped to a physical screen?

Comment: Well, you could write your own monitor with `XQueryTree` and see if any windows overlap that area. I say so only half-sarcasticly - you may have to resort to such a similar hack if no answers come.

Comment: @new123456 : Unfortunately that's outside the programming languages that I handle reasonably ( or minimally even ).

Comment: I've found [this](http://superuser.com/questions/258669/multiple-monitors-under-x-eliminating-gaps-due-to-different-monitor-heights) (not an answer because I haven't read it fully)

Comment: @new123456: the link is to this exact question. Is recursion the answer :-) ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=53825) link. No idea how I managed that.

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically if your window manager supports the Xinerama extensions (yes, even if you're using nVidia TwinView without Xinerama.)  I use [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) as my window manager and it handles this perfectly - no windows are ever shown in the off-screen areas.

Alternatively you could switch to separate X screens instead of using TwinView/Xinerama.  This method removes any off-screen area, at the expense of being unable to move windows between screens.